# How to set interval time for TimePickerDialog?

Tags: android, kotlin, timepicker

I use TimePickerDialog that show hours and minutes. I need that show only 30 minutes interval from start 00:30. That should be like 00:30, 1:00, 1:30, 2:00. I searched solution but I did not get clear answer. Can I do this with TimePickerDialog?

TimeReminderDialog.kt

```
binding.tvSelectionTerm.setOnClickListener {
         val dialog = TimePickerDialog(
                requireContext(),
                AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT,
                timeSetListener(WhichTimeType.TERMS_TIME),
                cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
                cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE),
                true,
            )
            if (termsBetweenTimeForDialog?.isEmpty() == true) {
                dialog.updateTime(1, 0)
            } else {
                dialog.updateTime(
                    dropZeroChar(WhichTimeUnitType.FOR_HOUR, WhichTimeType.TERMS_TIME),
                    dropZeroChar(WhichTimeUnitType.FOR_MINUTE, WhichTimeType.TERMS_TIME)
                )
            }
            dialog.show()
}

private fun timeSetListener(whichTimeType: WhichTimeType) =
        TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener { _, hour, minutes ->
            cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour)
            cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minutes)
            val myFormat = "HH:mm" // mention the format you need
            val sdf = SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.getDefault())
            val selectedTime = sdf.format(cal.timeInMillis)
```

Comment: It's really crazy they don't have this customization yet. Go back 10 years people asked about the same issue and Android team still haven't added this yet...

Comment: Yes. Unfortunately they did not do anything yet.

Comment: Btw, I solved by using MaterialDateTimePicker. 3rd party, but it works for me. Simple call to`setTimeInterval` method. https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker